# Couldn't connect to a shared mailbox with my python script

Tags: python, json, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to make a python script that connects itself to an office shared mailbox.
I'm trying to build an access token and to connect with Graph's API but i should have missed some steps maybe on the Microsoft side.

Here's my code (a bit updated compared to yesterday):

```
import msal
import json
import requests
import creds as c
import logging


tenant_id = c.tenant_id
authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{c.tenant_id}'
client_id = c.client_id
client_secret = c.secret
scope = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, authority=authority, client_credential=client_secret)
result = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes=scope, account=None)

if not result:
    logging.info("No suitable token exists in cache. Let's get a new one from AAD.")
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)

if "access_token" in result:
    graph_data = requests.get(
        #'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users',
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']},
        url=f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{c.user_id}/messages').json()
    print("Graph API call result: ")
    print(json.dumps(graph_data, indent=2))
else:
    print(result.get("error"))
    print(result.get("error_description"))
    print(result.get("correlation_id"))
```

And here's the output :
`Erreur: 403, {"error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."`

I tried to do what 'AmanpreetSingh-MSFT' said here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/197819/insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-operation

But it doesn't do anything.

I tried before with IMAP4_SSL but doesn't works, keep having 'LOGIN failed' in the output.

I did my application on Entra, i granted the permissions, might have all the necessary IDs (client, tenant, secret, user).
I enabled App and Delegated authorization on Azure.
I've the latest version of py and pip.

Edit :
Here's my token decoded :

```
aud: https://graph.microsoft.com
iss: https://sts.windows.net/8b6b7804-1008-4f7d-b866-65d2e04d0a63/
iat: 1701244213
nbf: 1701244213
exp: 1701248113
aio: E2VgYFhmyFf87vTS8D+uYt8jTvmzAgA=
app_displayname: Redmine Informatique
appid: 1cb255a3-4211-4bba-a741-8158331c26e9
appidacr: 1
idp: https://sts.windows.net/8b6b7804-1008-4f7d-b866-65d2e04d0a63/
idtyp: app
oid: 752e091f-2a92-4838-ab77-ab3b03953d73
rh: 0.AQwABHhriwgQfU-4ZmXS4E0KYwMAAAAAAAAAwAAAAAAAAACWAAA.
sub: 752e091f-2a92-4838-ab77-ab3b03953d73
tenant_region_scope: EU
tid: 8b6b7804-1008-4f7d-b866-65d2e04d0a63
uti: ZUgikoxms0a32rCuFh5OAg
ver: 1.0
wids: ['0997a1d0-0d1d-4acb-b408-d5ca73121e90']
xms_tcdt: 1426243296
xms_tdbr: EU
```

I have no URI configured on Azure, i don't know what am I supposed to set.

Update 2 :

I tried with my own account and the output  it the same.

```
Graph API call result: 
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
  }
}
```

I think that first my app miss some permissions, and then i may build a wrong token of connect with the wrong way...
Any Microsoft expert ? The doc doesn't help me that much.

Update :
It now Works thanks to @sridevi
I just added the wrong permissions (Delegated instead of Application permissions).
I may just followed the wrong tutorial.
Thank you all for your help !

Comment: the best place to start is take your token and have a look at it in https://jwt.io/ and check what permission are being returned. You can get that error due to not having the permissions consented to, but what you get back in the token will tell you either way.

Comment: Could you include `API permissions` snip of your application from Portal by editing your question?

Comment: @GlenScales i tried to put my token on jwt.io but it says "invalid signature".
I tried with a fake token too, and it returns "invalid token". Seems to be permission issue but i don't know what i could've missed.

Comment: @Sridevi i have no URI configured for my app yet, it may be the problem ?
I don't really understood what u needed but i tried smth... Feel free to reply if i didn't tried the right thing ! (update of my post done)

Comment: @skrylexx_ The error usually occurs if you missed granting permissions of Application type while using client credentials flow. Please add `Mail.Read` permission of **Application** type in your application and make sure to grant admin consent to it.

Comment: @Sridevi I did it, add every Mail and User permissions but nothing changed. Maybe my app miss permission with my user ?
U can add me on discord : asticrocolasticoptere
Or mail me : a.demeuleneire@ecoles-epsi.net

If u need more informations, feel free to reply again

Comment: Could you include this [image](https://i.imgur.com/PvVpC6L.png) of your application by editing your question?

Comment: When I ran your code without granting `Mail.Read` permission of **Application** type, I too got same error like [this](https://i.imgur.com/iPczDHG.png)

Comment: @Sridevi it was already done, here's the image

Comment: @skrylexx_ You added `Mail.Read` permission of **Delegated** type. Please add  `Mail.Read` permission of **Application** type.

Comment: It works now !!
Ty so much for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To resolve the error, you need to grant permissions of **`Application`** type in your application while using **client credentials** flow.

I registered one Azure AD application and granted **`Mail.Read`** permission of **Application** type as below:

[image]

If you grant permissions of **Application** type, you can find them in **`roles`** claim of decoded token like this:

[image]

When I ran your code in my environment now, I got the **response** with user's messages successfully as below:

```py
import msal
import json
import requests
import creds as c
import logging

tenant_id = c.tenant_id
authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{c.tenant_id}'
client_id = c.client_id
client_secret = c.secret
scope = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, authority=authority, client_credential=client_secret)
result = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes=scope, account=None)

if not result:
    logging.info("No suitable token exists in cache. Let's get a new one from AAD.")
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)

if "access_token" in result:
    graph_data = requests.get(
        #'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users',
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']},
        url=f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{c.user_id}/messages').json()
    print("Graph API call result: ")
    print(json.dumps(graph_data, indent=2))
else:
    print(result.get("error"))
    print(result.get("error_description"))
    print(result.get("correlation_id"))
```

**Response:**

[image]